# Set variables for union query

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2008-r2, union

I have the below union query and it goes through 15 levels; I only show three so you get the idea.  I would like to set variables at the top for the input so I don't need to change 15x3 criteria every time. Variables I would like to set once at the top to apply to all are:
pyh_per_cc 
pyh_tc_batch 
pyh_no01 (note: this is an 'IN' criteria)

Is there a way to do this?  I am using SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008 R2 in case that makes any difference.
Thanks in advance!

```
select hr_pe_id, pyh_no01 pyh_no, pyh_amt01 pyh_amt
from pyh_hst_dtl 
where pyh_no01 <> 0
and pyh_per_cc = '1301001'
and pyh_tc_batch = 'P1301001'
and pyh_no01 in ('2100','2101','2105','2108','2113','2115','2117','2118','2119')
union
select hr_pe_id, pyh_no02 pyh_no, pyh_amt02 pyh_amt
from pyh_hst_dtl
where pyh_no02 <> 0
and pyh_per_cc = '1301001'
and pyh_tc_batch = 'P1301001'
and pyh_no02 in ('2100','2101','2105','2108','2113','2115','2117','2118','2119')
union
select hr_pe_id, pyh_no03 pyh_no, pyh_amt03 pyh_amt
from pyh_hst_dtl
where pyh_no03 <> 0
and pyh_per_cc = '1301001'
and pyh_tc_batch = 'P1301001'
and pyh_no03 in  ('2100','2101','2105','2108','2113','2115','2117','2118','2119')
order by hr_pe_id
```

Comment: Would it be possible / worthwhile to use a temporary 'memory table'? Is this an 'un-pivot'?

Comment: Not sure what an 'un-pivot' is...?

Comment: UNPIVOT performs almost the reverse operation of PIVOT, by rotating columns into rows. That is what i think you are trying to do? [standard-t-sql-unpivot](http://www.ingenioussql.com/2013/05/09/standard-t-sql-unpivot/). It is sometimes easier to do outside of the database using a 'procedural language'

Comment: It's a funny table, not sure why they built it like this, but for reporting purposes they have a 'normalized' category that does the unpivot.  Unfortunately that category is not available via SQL.  I will research the unpivot a bit and see if that will work. Thanks!

Comment: can you put the list of items in the `IN()` clause in a table?  Or even a temp table, then you can use a (or many) joins.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, missed that you're testing the value of the same field twice.

Would this work?

```
CREATE TABLE #pyh_nos(pyh_no char(4));

insert into #pyh_nos values ('2100');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2101');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2105');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2108');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2113');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2115');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2117');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2118');
insert into #pyh_nos values ('2119');

select 
hr_pe_id, pyh_no01 pyh_no, pyh_amt01 pyh_amt
from 
pyh_hst_dtl h left outer join
#pyh_nos p1 on 
pyh_no01 = p1.pyh_no left outer join
#pyh_nos p2 on 
pyh_no02 = p2.pyh_no
...
left outer join
#pyh_nos p15 on 
pyh_no15 = p15.pyh_no
where  
pyh_per_cc = '1301001'
and pyh_tc_batch = 'P1301001' and
(p1.pyh_no is not null or
...
p15.pyh_no is not null)
```

Comment: Excellent observation.  This is exactly how OP needs to simplify their query.

Comment: this query is not the same.  Each level listed in the question looks at the values of a different field, not always pyh_no01, but pyh_no02 and pyh_no03

Comment: ?  this query also looks for values in 15 different fields

Comment: The pyh_no01-15 corresponds with the pyh_amt01-15: they represent all of the paycheck deduction codes and amounts that get taken on a check.

Comment: I am definitely open to any suggestions on ways to simplify as I got this from someone else. My SQL knowledge wasn't in depth enough to figure out a better way.

Comment: sorry, missed that.  you're checking that the same field is in a list and also <> 0?  then you don't need the <>0 condition at all.